# How to automate adding lines in a plotly graph in R?

Tags: r, grouping, plotly

I know I can use `addtrace` to add lines to a plot, but I would like to do this automatically for groups in my dataset.

Data looks like this:

```
X     Y      Group
1     2       0.1
...   ...     0.1
10    20      0.1
1     5       0.4
...   ...     0.4
10    50      0.4
1     7       0.6
...   ...     0.6
10    70      0.6
```

If I do the following:

```
p <- plotly(type="scatter", mode="markers", data=df, x=~X, y=~Y, color = ~Group)
```

I do get the desired result, but the color is shown as a continuous spectrum, instead as 3 separate lines in the legend.

How can I combine the result I get through `addtrace` with the `color` mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is shown as continuous spectrum, because the group variable is numeric. You can change it to `as.factor(Group)` to get the desired result as in:

```
p <- plot_ly(type="scatter", mode="markers", data=df, x=~X, y=~Y, color = ~as.factor(Group))
```

Comment: Hero! Is this documented somewhere? If so, I must have been blind, as I have looked through the plotly help file back and forth.

Comment: Yes, have a look at the excellent book by Cason Sievert: https://cpsievert.github.io/plotly_book/scatter-traces.html  There he describes in detail which variable type will result in what outcome.